# Accessing nested static const

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, class-constants

I'm trying to use a nested constant within WPF, but XAML doesn't seem to handle nested static classes.

```
namespace MyCommon.Constants
{
    public static class Constants
    {
        public static class Formatting
        {
            public static class DateTime
            {
                public const string BritishDateToString = "dd-MM-yy";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Import the namespace

```
xmlns:constants="clr-namespace:MyCommon.Constants;assembly=MyCommon"
```

The following lines gives an error

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={x:Static constants:Constants.Formatting.DateTime.BritishDateTimeToString}}" Header="Date" />
```

Comment: may be BritishDateToString should be static

Comment: @Florian, const => static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `+` for accessing nested classes

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={x:Static constants:Constants+Formatting+DateTime.BritishDateTimeToString}}" Header="Date" />
```